# Tidy way to add column if missing from data frame

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am looking for a tidy way to add a missing column if not present in the dataset. For example, df1 does not contain column "c".

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=c(1:3, NA), b=c(NA,2:4))
```

desired output:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=c(1:3, NA), b=c(NA,2:4), c=c(NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to overwrite the column if it is already present in your data you can use `add_column` along with an `if` condition to check if the column is already present.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(a=c(1:3, NA), b=c(NA,2:4))
if(!'c' %in% names(df1)) df1 <- df1 %>% add_column(c = NA)
df1

#   a  b  c
#1  1 NA NA
#2  2  2 NA
#3  3  3 NA
#4 NA  4 NA
```

Answer (score -1):

Tidy way would be `dplyr::mutate` I guess.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(c = c(NA))
```

No need to specify multiple NA as it will be recycled to fill all rows of the data frame.

Comment: That doesn't address the "if missing" part of the question.

Comment: Not sure if that's a -1 crime in this case but I take your point :)